# Cosmos DB "Partial Update"/Patch, cant set new property value to null

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-cosmosdb

I'm trying out the Cosmos DB SDK's new [Patch/Partial Update-functionality](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/partial-document-update-getting-started) (for .NET)

When adding a new property I use

```
 var patchOperations = new List<PatchOperation>(){
       PatchOperation.Add<string>("/FavoriteColor", **null**)
 };


 await container.PatchItemAsync<T>(
                          id: myId,
                          partitionKey: new PartitionKey(myPk),
                          patchOperations: patchOperations);
```

The problem is, that it throws at the PatchOperation-Add() if I set second parameter to null (with message *"Value cannot be null"*). I can set any non-null string and it works well. I just wonder if this isn't supported yet or if I missed something.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to github user rvdvelden ([source](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/issues/2931#issuecomment-1029768625)), this work around appears to work perfectly:

```
private JToken NullValue { get { return new JProperty("nullValue", null).Value; } }
```

Used in this way:

```
operations.Add(PatchOperation.Set("\customer", value ?? NullValue));
```

Comment: Would it be possible to add a solution using system.text.json please? prefer not to add newtonsoft just for this workaround, many thanks

Answer (score 2):

[Remove](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.patchoperation.remove?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Cosmos_PatchOperation_Remove_System_String_) is one alternative if the intent is to remove field/property.

Answer (score 1):

This is **`not supported`** with Patch yet,

However, if you want to remove the entire property you need to use [Remove](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.patchoperation.remove?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Cosmos_PatchOperation_Remove_System_String_) Operation

Comment: Just an update on this, this should work with Node SDK , there is an issue with dotnet sdk which the team will check and unblock

Comment: That's really sad because Remove will result in an error when the property does not exist... in my case, I can't be sure whether the property exists or not so I cannot use the patch API.
I am quite disappointed. We were waiting quite some time for that feature now and on the first day I have already figured out several scenarios that I cannot handle with the partial updates.

Comment: Can you provide a link to where is says it is not supported? Thanks

Comment: I reported this issue here https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/issues/2931

Answer (score 1):

Good news, from SDK [version 3.27.0](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/releases/tag/3.27.0) it's supported with the `Set` operation

`PatchOperation.Set("\fieldToUpdate", null)`